# How use "patch" command meant for *nix on OS X?

Tags: macos, patch

In order to build the Utah Raster Toolkit for Mac OS X, I need to apply a patch file `urt-3.0.patch1` to the source. The instructions say to use:

```
patch -p -N <urt-3.0.patch1
```

But that doesn't seem to be the right syntax for the OS X version of `patch`; I get error:

```
patch: **** strip count -N is not a number
```

What is the correct syntax in order to accomplish the intent the instructions?

Comment: What platform are those instructions written for? You might have linked to the instructions. Anyway, just try without the `-p` and `-N` options. It will probably work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a number after the -p option, or, as Ken suggests, omit it.  Try -p0 if you want to keep it.  Use `man patch` at the OSX command line to get descriptions of what these options do.